# Docker / APT-GET cant find a package

Tags: linux, docker

I have a device running Raspberry PI (Debian - bulleye), and I enter this command:

```
apt show raspi-config
```

which yields this:
[image]

and I see that the API-Sources has this:

```
deb http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian bullseye/main arm64 Packages
```

so I figure I'll add that line to /etc/apt/sources.list after the last line:
[image]

so I try this in my docker build script
[image]

and try to build the docker image
[image]

I have the raspi-config on the device, but how can I install it on the docker image?

UPDATE:  learning that apt update is required? but then I get these error messages:
[image]

Comment: out of scope of docker stuff, there's a mistype in apt sources.list, format of lines is something like `deb http://site.dom/debian distro part1 part2 ...`. Supposing for the above example it should be `deb http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian bullseye main contrib non-free`

Comment: I've looked at rpi3b at my hand: there raspbian sources.list goes with a bit different line `deb http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian bullseye main contrib non-free`, maybe it's another one option of the same archive site

Comment: I added both, but no joy...the "apt show" command, does that not give us a clue as to the "package source"

Comment: I suggest to leave only one archive repo, for example this `deb http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian bullseye main contrib non-free`
and then run `apt update` and then `apt install raspi-config`

Comment: looks like there's no raspbian pubkey installed on that system (in my case it was with raspbian os). Try to do that with your original line, i.e. comment out this `deb http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian ...` and add your original `deb http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian bullseye main contrib non-free`, then the same `apt update` and `apt install raspi-config`. I hope it helps

Comment: tried that ... no joy... better luck with this in my docker build file:
RUN wget https://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian/pool/main/r/raspi-config/raspi-config_20230214_all.deb -P /tmp
RUN apt update -y
RUN apt-get install libnewt0.52 whiptail parted triggerhappy lua5.1 alsa-utils psmisc initramfs-tools -y 
RUN apt-get install -y
RUN dpkg -i /tmp/raspi-config_20230214_all.deb
RUN apt update -y
RUN apt install raspi-config

Comment: I get the raspi-config on my device drive, and it executes, but in the output I also get this:
"/usr/bin/raspi-config: 12: ps: not found" and then following the host name!

Comment: `dpkg -S /bin/ps` says `procps: /bin/ps`. I.e. `apt install procps` for `ps` program

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)  It's not clear whether this is actually a programming question or not; if you're just trying to configure APT (you can't include a PNG file in `/etc/apt/sources.list`) then another site like [unix.se] might be a more appropriate place to ask.

Comment: @yvs2014 Looks like I got educated on images - the raspi-config was not in the image, and the context in which it was running was incorrect.  Even if I got raspi-config into the image (which I eventually did) it would not run correctly due to the context.

If you put in this answer, I'll mark it, as it was your input that helped me find the issue. Thanks!

Comment: @codeputer In principle, it was expected. Docker is kinda some type of virtualization, and these things connected with hardware (like gpio) usualy are not so easy to map into a virtual environment. Anyway, sorting it out you have became familiar how to deal with unixes.

Answer (score 0):

It was a painful lesson in Docker Images and the host that the Docker service is running on.  I had given the docker container full permissions to the board (Raspberry PI), but their is a difference between a file path for the host, and a file path for the container.... Of course you say, but what if there is a path on the container which is the same as the host?  Which folder will be returned when the path is executed?  The answer is the preference is the container.  I added /host/.... to docker image permissions and it started working.

Once that lesson was learned, the next lesson was running Raspi-config on the image rather than the host and the context difference between those two and something called a shebang.

I was trying to run the raspi-config on the host, but the code, running in the docker container... doesn't work due to the context of where the code is running and the "shebang" operator (at least that is my best understanding).

The solution was I needed to rethink and take a different approach.  Hard lessons are learned well.  Won't make that mistake again.